# Switched hosts, having issues with .htaccess 301 redirects from old website to new website

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a blog that was originally built on blogengine.net; I switched over to Wordpress, and changed to a different hosting company.

I'm using their Cpanel to redirect 3 or 4 pages to reflect their new URLs. Specifically, I'm trying in one instance to perm 301 redirect:

http://www.realtruthnow.org/blog/post/2013/01/01/What-do-people-in-Newtown-want-for-the-holidays

to

http://www.realtruthnow.org/ny-governor-signs-nations-first-gun-control-bill-since-newtown/

When I do this using the host's Cpanel, it creates an entry in my root .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^realtruthnow\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.realtruthnow\.org$
RewriteRule ^blog\/post\/2013\/01\/01\/What\-do\-people\-in\-Newtown\-want\-for\-the
\-holidays$ "http\:\/\/www\.realtruthnow\.org\/ny\-governor\-signs\-nations\-first
\-gun\-control\-bill\-since\-newtown\/" [R=301,L]
```

This didn't work. So I googled, and tried putting this at the bottom of the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /http://www.realtruthnow.org/blog/post/2013/01/01/What-do-people-
in-Newtown-want-for-the-holidays http://www.realtruthnow.org/ny-governor-signs-nations-
first-gun-control-bill-since-newtown/
```

That didn't work either.  I only need to do this for 3 or 4 pages that I'm aware of.  Does anybody know how I can accomplish this redirect from an old host to a new host, so when someone clicks the old link, they're 301'd to the new link?  Any guidance would be appreciated!

**Solved**

I installed "simple 301 redirects" plugin, and that didn't work when I put the old URL http://www.realtruthnow.org/ in ... but when I omitted that, and just put /blog/post/2013/01/01/What-do-people-in-Newtown-want-for-the-holidays in for my old URL, BAM -- it worked!  Below is the plugin if anybody needs it.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

Comment: I'm not sure why, faa; that's why I posed the question ... lol ... when I click the old link, it just brings me to my 404 error page, but not the page I'm trying to redirect it to.

Comment: Okay. That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^realtruthnow\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.realtruthnow\.org$
RewriteRule ^blog/post/2013/01/01/What-do-people-in-Newtown-want-for-the-holidays/?$  http://www.realtruthnow.org/ny-governor-signs-nations-first-gun-control-bill-since-newtown/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

It's the same rule that cPanel generated, without quotes and escaping.

It redirects permanently this

`http://www.realtruthnow.org/blog/post/2013/01/01/What-do-people-in-Newtown-want-for-the-holidays`

To this

`http://www.realtruthnow.org/ny-governor-signs-nations-first-gun-control-bill-since-newtown/`

Comment: @Jason I think the problem is with character case, there are some in uppercase, so I updated my answer adding the `NC` flag.

Comment: Hi faa.  Thank you for trying to help!  I tried the revised solution, and if you click the old link, you'll see it still brings me a 404 error.  Maybe I'll try putting in a support ticket ... lol ... I really do appreciate you taking the time to try to help, faa, and if you have any other suggestions, I'd gladly try 'em!  Thanks again for trying to help!

Comment: ¿Did you try adding the `NC` flag? ¿Are you sure page `ny-governor-signs-nations-first-gun-control-bill-since-newtown` exist with exactly the same string?  You are welcome anyway.

Comment: Yes, I included the NC flag, faa.  I think my webhost is just messed up or something.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Jason I checked the link. That's a WP blog. The problem is with the permalinks, I am pretty sure.

Comment: Yes, it's Wordpress ... but I don't see how permalinks would be an issue ... technically, it should still work, I'd think ... I'm more used to asp.net/IIS 7 ... and it'd be easy to set up a redirect that way, but I'm new to PHP and Wordpress ....

Comment: Try checking the page `slug` in the editor to be sure it is the same you have in your link.

Comment: That was a good suggestion, faa, but indeed, the permalink slugs are the same as what we had in our .htaccess ... I'll try talking to one of these live-chat people at gator, my shared hosting company ... I really do appreciate you hangin' in there and tryin' to help! I'll get it to work, sooner or later .... and I'm not goin' back to blogengine.net ever again; I really do like WP.

Comment: You are welcome again. If you think I can help with this issue in the future, in any other way. Just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody comes across a similar problem, I solved the problem of redirecting old blogengine.net links (from a windows server) to Wordpress links with a new host.

It turns out that it's a quirky Wordpress type of thing.

I installed "simple 301 redirects" plugin, and that didn't work when I put the old **ENTIRE** URL http://www.realtruthnow.org/blog/post/2013/01/01/What-do-people-in-Newtown-want-for-the-holidays in ...

But when I omitted the root, and just put /blog/post/2013/01/01/What-do-people-in-Newtown-want-for-the-holidays in for my old URL, BAM -- it worked!

Below is the plugin if anybody needs it.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/